Tensorboard failed to load runs only in time series tab
I'm building models using pytorch on Ubuntu platform. I use tensorboard (torch.utils.tensorboard / tensorboardX) to log training informations. I access these logs on windows Chrome browser. Scalars, histograms, etc. are showing normally, but timeseries shows nothing. There's popup saying failed to fetch runs. How should I fix this?
More Info
I'm using vscode remote ssh for developing. I use vscode server to forward the port for tensorboard server.
In vscode tensorboard extension, it runs a browser on server host (I guess) to read log files. In this situation, time series also doesn't show anything.
Versions
python==3.8.10
tensorboard==2.14.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorboardX==0.7.2
vscode==1.91.1
vscode-server==?
ubuntu==
torch==1.7.1+cu110
Chrome==127.0.6533.73

I tried to copy log folder to windows local host and run tensorboard, time series tab displays normally.
I added --verbose option of tensorboard to view logs. When scalar tab is activated, there're http post logs. However, when time series tab is activated, it just constantly reloading. It can read several runs, but doesn't post. On windows platform (which displays normally), there're several get and post logs.
I want to know if there is any mis-configured options that can fix this problem.
